# Why can't I return to the original page after the payment in the Alipay sandbox?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Why after the payment of Alipay sandbox, the return address is http://127.0.0.1:5173 will be rejected, but changed to http://localhost:5173 can return normally, I am a front-end beginner, and there is no specific code information of the back end, which may be a cross-domain problem, but I still want to know what the specific principle is, and why it can be modified into localhost. Thank you for being willing to answer questions. I did not find the answer to solve my doubts on the Internet, which may be that I have learned too little, and I still need to improve my ability constantly

Comment: While both `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` refer to the local machine, they are treated differently by the browser. `localhost` is a special hostname that resolves to the loopback IP address `127.0.0.1`, but it also bypasses certain security restrictions. Some browser security features may treat requests to `localhost` differently from requests to `127.0.0.1`. This can sometimes help circumvent cross-domain issues during development.